# Get certain processor CPU usage using C#

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, processor

I found the below code on Google to get certain processor CPU usage

```
int processorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
PerformanceCounter myAppCpu = new PerformanceCounter( "Process", "% Processor Time", "chrome", true);
float cpuUsage = myAppCpu.NextValue() / processorCount;
```

but in my TaskManager, one disk image may have multi PIDs.

[image]

so, I want to know, is the CPU usage this code counted the total usage by the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GetProcessTimes function from the kernel32.dll.
See the .NET usage here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetProcessTimes.html

The first parameter is the handle of the process. Use either  `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle` or `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(123).Handle` or any other process instance.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CPUUsage
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var status = new CPUStatus(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess());
        Console.WriteLine("CPU usage: {0}", status.RawUsage);

        var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");
        if (processes.Any())
        {
            var status2 = new CPUStatus(processes.First());
            Console.WriteLine("Devenv CPU usage: {0}", status.RawUsage);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Devenv CPU usage: {0}", status.RawUsage);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class to retrieve the CPU values.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public class CPUStatus
{

    #region "Members"
    private ProcessTimes _ProcessTimes = new ProcessTimes();
    private long _OldUserTime;
    private long _OldKernelTime;
    private DateTime _OldUpdate;
    private Int32 _RawUsage;        
    private object _Lock = new object();
    private IntPtr _processHandle;
    #endregion

    #region "Constructor"
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the CPUStatus instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process to monitor</param>
    public CPUStatus(System.Diagnostics.Process process)
    {
        _OldUpdate = DateTime.MinValue;          
        _processHandle = process.Handle;

        InitValues();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Imports
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetProcessTimes(IntPtr hProcess, out long lpCreationTime, out long lpExitTime, out long lpKernelTime, out long lpUserTime);
    #endregion

    #region "Private methods"
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the initial values
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private void InitValues()
    {
        try
        {

            if ((GetProcessTimes(_processHandle, out _ProcessTimes.RawCreationTime, out _ProcessTimes.RawExitTime, out _ProcessTimes.RawKernelTime, out _ProcessTimes.RawUserTime)))
            {
                // convert the values to DateTime values
                _ProcessTimes.ConvertTime();

                _OldUserTime = _ProcessTimes.UserTime.Ticks;
                _OldKernelTime = _ProcessTimes.KernelTime.Ticks;
                _OldUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _OldUpdate = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes the usage values
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private void Refresh()
    {
        lock (_Lock)
        {

            if ((GetProcessTimes(_processHandle, out _ProcessTimes.RawCreationTime, out _ProcessTimes.RawExitTime, out _ProcessTimes.RawKernelTime, out _ProcessTimes.RawUserTime)))
            {
                // convert the values to DateTime values
                _ProcessTimes.ConvertTime();

                UpdateCPUUsage(_ProcessTimes.UserTime.Ticks, _ProcessTimes.KernelTime.Ticks);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Could not retrieve process times");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// updates the cpu usage (cpu usgae = UserTime + KernelTime)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newUserTime"></param>
    /// <param name="newKernelTime"></param>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    private void UpdateCPUUsage(long newUserTime, long newKernelTime)
    {
        long UpdateDelay = 0;
        long UserTime = newUserTime - _OldUserTime;
        long KernelTime = newKernelTime - _OldKernelTime;

        if (_OldUpdate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            _RawUsage = Convert.ToInt32((UserTime + KernelTime) * 100);
        }
        else
        {
            // eliminates "divided by zero"
            if (DateTime.Now.Ticks == _OldUpdate.Ticks)
                Thread.Sleep(100);

            UpdateDelay = DateTime.Now.Ticks - _OldUpdate.Ticks;

            _RawUsage = Convert.ToInt32(((UserTime + KernelTime) * 100) / UpdateDelay);
        }

        _OldUserTime = newUserTime;
        _OldKernelTime = newKernelTime;
        _OldUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Properties"
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the CPU usage
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public Int32 RawUsage
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_Lock)
            {
                Refresh();
                return _RawUsage;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region "internal classes"
    private struct ProcessTimes
    {
        public DateTime CreationTime;
        public DateTime ExitTime;
        public DateTime KernelTime;
        public DateTime UserTime;

        public long RawCreationTime;
        public long RawExitTime;
        public long RawKernelTime;
        public long RawUserTime;

        public void ConvertTime()
        {
            CreationTime = FiletimeToDateTime(RawCreationTime);
            ExitTime = FiletimeToDateTime(RawExitTime);
            KernelTime = FiletimeToDateTime(RawKernelTime);
            UserTime = FiletimeToDateTime(RawUserTime);
        }

        private DateTime FiletimeToDateTime(long FileTime)
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(FileTime);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new DateTime();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

}

}
```